# Unable to connect to more than one apache ignite server at a single instance

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am new to Apache Ignite. I have an application for which I am trying to utilize Apache Ignite for a distributed cache.

I currently have 3 servers to process to serve the incoming requests and if one server is down, one of the other two servers would need to handle the request.

I have configured the "REPLICATED Cache" in the Cache Configuration and have configured the IP Address for the servers in use using "TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder".

The topology snapshot always shows me one client and one server when all three servers are up, and killing one server disconnects the client node even if the other two servers are still up.

I am having the same issue when using multicast node discovery. One server is identified and the other two servers do not join the topology even though they have the same multicast group configuration.

Comment: Do the servers discover each other? What is the topology print out on all 3 servers?

Comment: This was the Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=1.0GB] on all 3 servers.                                                            The issue is resolved if I start the servers once the client is up. This is the current Topology snapshot [ver=6, servers=3, clients=1, CPUs=76, heap=14.0GB]                                                                                         If the servers are already started before the client is up it looks like the client does not identify these servers and the topology snapshot is not updated.

Comment: It looks like the IP finder does not provide full list of addresses. Can you provide your IP finder configuration?

Comment: Are these the IDs of servers or clients? If these are the IDs of servers, then they should discover each other. Additionally, please make sure that operating system firewalls are disabled on all the servers.

Comment: Hi Dimitriy, Thank you for your response. These are ipAddress of servers. Yes, the firewalls are disabled. It works now, However I am having an issue when I try to use multicast to identify the servers instead of ipAddresses. It identifies only one out of the three servers up - i.e The server on the same machine as the client and does not identify the other two servers.

Comment: <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder"> 
                        <property name="multicastGroup" value="224.2.2.3"> 
                        </property>
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                            </list>
                        </property> 
                    </bean> <!-- Comfiguration used for multicast - on server and client -->

Comment: @Nikhil I guess that multicast in your network is not allowed, but still works within your machine. Can this be the case? Please check your network settings.

Comment: @Valentin I did check my network settings. It does not look like a network issue.

Comment: @Nikhil How did you check that multicast is enabled in your network? What OS are you on?

Comment: @Valentin I checked by running netstat -g command and ip maddr show on the three Linux machines. I got the below responses on all 3 machines for  "netstat -g" 
IPv6/IPv4 Group Memberships
Interface       RefCnt Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      all-systems.mcast.net
eth0            1      224.2.2.3
eth0            1      all-systems.mcast.net

Comment: @Nikhil That's weird, I have the same output and everything works fine for me. Are all the nodes in the same network? Do I understand correctly that it works for you without multicast? Can you just use statically configured addresses?

Comment: @Valentin Yes, All the nodes are on the same network. Yes, It works fine without the multicast option. I require to use the multicast option as the system scales upward.

Comment: @Nikhil Take a look at https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.5.0.final/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/jdbc/TcpDiscoveryJdbcIpFinder.html and https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.5.0.final/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/sharedfs/TcpDiscoverySharedFsIpFinder.html. These IP finders can be good alternatives for efficient scaling of your cluster in case multicast is not working for some reason.

Comment: @Valentin Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into it.